# SFML Sprite isn't showing on the window but it isn't giving me any errors

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using SFML for creating a small game for practice, a replica of the old Tanks game I played when I was young on some type of console.

I've encountered a strage thing when I'm trying to draw the player. I'm saying strange because at first it was showing, so I don't think something is wrong with my function, but after I made a derived class for the enemy tanks and made a new file for that I had some nesting problems with linking all the files togheter(5 files, 1 cpp and 4 headers). After I figured that out, I ran into this problem and can't find any solution to it. It was working before that problem and now it doesn't anymore.

I checked the texture, if it is loading, the position I set it to, they are ok.

Here is the class for the player tank

```
class tank{

protected:
sf::FloatRect boundingBox;
sf::Sprite tankSprite;

bullet *mBullet;
public :
tank(); // constructor

bullet * get_ptr(){return mBullet;}
sf::FloatRect get_boundingBox(){return boundingBox;}

void setRotation(float);
void show(){game.draw(tankSprite);}
void update();
void shoot(){mBullet = new bullet(tankSprite);}
};
```

And this is the code in my main where I update the world and draw on my window

```
if(!stop)
    Me.update();

if(Me.get_ptr()->isFired()==true)
    Me.get_ptr()->update();

// Output on the window
game.clear();
Me.show();
if(Me.get_ptr()->isFired()==true)
    Me.get_ptr()->show();
game.display();
```

Side note : game is the render window and is globally declared( I know it's bad practice, I'm slowing getting to ditch this bad habit)

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Tank.h"

int main()
{
tank Me;

init();
while (game.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (game.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            game.close();
        else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            stop=false;
            switch(event.key.code)
            {
                case sf::Keyboard::W:
                {
                    Me.setRotation(0);
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::D:
                {
                    Me.setRotation(90);
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::S:
                {
                    Me.setRotation(180);
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::A:
                {
                    Me.setRotation(270);
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                {
                    game.close();
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::Space:
                {
                    if(Me.get_ptr()->isFired()==false)Me.shoot();
                    break;
                }
                case sf::Keyboard::LControl:
                {
                    stop=true;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!stop)
        Me.update();

    if(Me.get_ptr()->isFired()==true)
        Me.get_ptr()->update();

    // Output on the window
    game.clear();
    Me.show();
    if(Me.get_ptr()->isFired()==true)
        Me.get_ptr()->show();
    game.display();
}
return 0;
}
```

init.h

```
#include<iostream>

bool stop;

sf::RenderWindow game(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "SFML");

sf::Texture myTankTexture;
sf::Texture bulletTexture;

void init(){

srand(time(NULL));

stop = true;

game.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
game.setFramerateLimit(60);

if(!myTankTexture.loadFromFile("tank.jpg"))
{
    std::cout<<"eroare la textura tank"<<std::endl;
}
myTankTexture.setSmooth(true);

if(!bulletTexture.loadFromFile("bullet.jpg"))
{
    std::cout<<"bullet texture error"<<std::endl;
}
bulletTexture.setSmooth(true);
}

sf::Vector2f rotationToDirection(int rotation){

sf::Vector2f dir;
switch (rotation)
{
    case 0:
    {
        dir.x=0.0;
        dir.y=-1.0;
        break;
    }
    case 90:
    {
        dir.x=1.0;
        dir.y=0.0;
        break;
    }
    case 180:
    {
        dir.x=0.0;
        dir.y=1.0;
        break;
    }
    case 270:
    {
        dir.x=-1.0;
        dir.y=0.0;
        break;
    }
}
return dir;
}
```

bullet.h

```
#include "init.h"

class bullet{

protected:
sf::Sprite bulletSprite;
sf::FloatRect boundingBox;
bool isBFired = false;
public:
bullet(sf::Sprite); // constructor
~bullet(){isBFired=false;}

sf::FloatRect get_boundingBox(){return boundingBox;}
bool isFired(){if(isBFired)return true;else return false;}
int collision();

void del(){delete this;}
void update();
void show(){game.draw(bulletSprite);}
};

bullet::bullet(sf::Sprite sprite){

isBFired = true;

bulletSprite.setTexture(bulletTexture);
bulletSprite.setOrigin(2.5,5.0);
bulletSprite.setRotation(sprite.getRotation());
     bulletSprite.setPosition(sprite.getPosition().x+rotationToDirection(bulletSprite.getRotation()).x*5.0,sprite.getPosition().y+rotationToDirection(bulletSprite.getRotation()).y*5.0);

boundingBox = bulletSprite.getLocalBounds();
}

int bullet::collision(){

if(bulletSprite.getPosition().x < 0
   || bulletSprite.getPosition().x > 400
   || bulletSprite.getPosition().y > 400
   || bulletSprite.getPosition().y < 0 )return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

void bullet::update(){

           bulletSprite.move(rotationToDirection(bulletSprite.getRotation()).x*6.0,rotationToDirection(bulletSprite.getRotation()).y*6.0);

if(collision()==1)
    delete this;
else
    boundingBox = bulletSprite.getLocalBounds();
}
```

tank.h

```
#include "bullet.h"

class tank{

protected:
sf::FloatRect boundingBox;
sf::Sprite tankSprite;

bullet *mBullet;
public :
tank(); // constructor

bullet * get_ptr(){return mBullet;}
sf::FloatRect get_boundingBox(){return boundingBox;}

void setRotation(float);
void show(){game.draw(tankSprite);}
void update();
void shoot(){mBullet = new bullet(tankSprite);}
};

tank::tank(){

tankSprite.setTexture(myTankTexture);
tankSprite.setOrigin(20,20);
tankSprite.setRotation(0);
tankSprite.setPosition(200,200);

boundingBox = tankSprite.getLocalBounds();
}

void tank::update(){

    tankSprite.move(rotationToDirection(tankSprite.getRotation()).x*3,rotationToDirection(tankSprite.getRotation()).y*3);

boundingBox = tankSprite.getLocalBounds();
}

void tank::setRotation(float rotation){

tankSprite.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal verifiable example. Also, your code is full of "code smells" *(e.g. using new to create a bullet and assigning it to a member pointer field, returning bullet by non-const ptr, etc...)*

Comment: @VittorioRomeo When I run my app I know I can move around because I can shoot and I see the bullet going as intended, but I just can't see myself, if I press the button which triggers the shoot() function it starts from where I am and I see the bullet. I don't know if I understood right what you mean by a minimal verifiable example, sorry if this isn't what you asked for.

Comment: @L Alex: something that I can copy-paste and compile easily on my system.

Comment: @LAlex [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the texture rectangle as far as I see, see if this helps you. When you set your tank sprite try :

> tankSprite.setTexture(myTankTexture, true);

Passing true will reset your texture rectangle to the size of the sprite, see the [SFML docs](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) for more information.

Also, you are creating the Tank class before calling init(), myTankTexture will be empty so the tank constructor uses that, and your texture is loaded later.

As they say in your language, "multa bafta" :)

Comment: Tried that now, unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I see the problem now, sorry. Swap these lines :

tank Me;
init();

You are creating the tank without the texture loaded, so your setTexture sets a blank texture. :)

Comment: Oh, right, it worked, thanks a lot, dumb me didn't noticed that, somehow I swapped them.